# std::filesystem::copy throws std::__ios_failure: what to do?

Tags: c++, exception, filesystems

The c++ program I'm working on invariably crashes when a certain directory is copied (using std::filesystem::copy) to a new location. The error message I get is:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::__ios_failure'
  what():  basic_filebuf::underflow error reading the file: Input/output error
Abort (core dumped)
```

I found the underlying problem when I tried to copy the very directory by hand. In this directory, containing jpg-images, there was one file apparently corrupt: If, from the command line I type (linux)

```
cp 20220810-15174296.jpg corrupt.jpg
cp: error reading '20220810-15174296.jpg': Input/output error
```

Apparently, something is wrong with the image 20220810-15174296.jpg, although it looks normal and can be displayed.
My question is not about this corrupt file, but ***how can I prevent my program from crashing.*** It seems that the offending exception std::__ios_failure cannot be caught.
A minimal program that is already showing the issue is

```
#include <exception>
#include <filesystem>
#include <iostream>

namespace fs = std::filesystem;

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
   try
   {
      fs::path src( "/path/to/src" );
      fs::path trg( "/path/to/trg" );
      fs::copy( src, trg, fs::copy_options::recursive );
   }
   catch ( ... )
   {
      std::cout << "ERROR occurred" << std::endl;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

No matter how I do the catch (std::system_error, fs::filesystem_error, std::exception, ...), the std::__ios_failure terminates the program as indicated. Also using the fs::copy overloads with the std::error_code argument does not change the situation.

The above program is compiled with either g++ (13.2.1) or clang++ (18.0.0), but the result is the same:

```
g++ -O3 --std=c++20 fscopy.cpp && ./a.out
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::__ios_failure'
  what():  basic_filebuf::underflow error reading the file: Input/output error
Abort (core dumped)
```

and

```
clang++ -O3 --std=c++20 fscopy.cpp && ./a.out
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::__ios_failure'
  what():  basic_filebuf::underflow error reading the file: Input/output error
Abort (core dumped)
```

Comment: Did you try  catching `std::filesystem::filesystem_error`? If you can't catch the exception, then did you try asking `copy()` to not throw an exception to begin with? You do that by using the overload that outputs a `std::error_code` instead.

Comment: Yes, I tried it all. No difference.

Comment: Is your disk full? What is the size of that image file? Try running `dmesg` from terminal after running `cp` command. What does its output show? https://askubuntu.com/q/509695

Comment: Related from a couple of years ago:   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67196597/terminate-called-after-throwing-an-instance-of-std-ios-failure-when-tryin     No solution to the problem then, so it seems unlikely you'll find an answer here.

Comment: I would guess that the `Input/output error` indicates a hardware problem (e.g. a dying harddisk). That is: you probably have more severe problems you should solve first (that's not to say that your program shouldn't gracefully handle dying harddisks)

Comment: @kiner_shah: No, the disk is not full, but your suggestion of running dmesg revealed that there is an issue with the filesystem indeed: after 'cp' of the culprit file,m I have many lines of the form:
```
[169427.491124] BTRFS warning (device sda1): csum failed root 5 ino 12206191 off 25460736 csum 0x2ac15d26 expected csum 0xc255e720 mirror 1
[169427.491142] BTRFS error (device sda1): bdev /dev/sda1 errs: wr 0, rd 0, flush 0, corrupt 27296, gen 0
```

Comment: @umlaute: Given the contents of my previous comment, you are probably right. I need to follow-up on this. But how can one gracefully handle these situations?

Comment: Run it under a debugger. For example with `gdb` use `catch throw` and maybe optionally put a breakpoint at `std::terminate`, then examine the call stack carefully to see if any `noexcept` function is involved. Watch for destructors as they are `noexcept` by default. You cannot catch exceptions thrown from `noexcept`  functions, they just call `std::terminate`.

Comment: Optionally, add your own `terminate_handler` so that you can put a breakpoint there to assist debugging.

Comment: @BertwimvanBeest, looks like corruption. The dmesg seems to say that checksum mismatch is detected. You may need to find a way to fix it, it's not C++ issue I think, more of a system issue.

Comment: If std::filesystem doesn't allow to capture the exception, you could always use the raw file apis of the OS and handle the error codes yourself. Of course, it wouldn't be portable (or you would need some #ifdefs and write dedicated code for the platforms you want to support). Alternatively, you could also try boost:: filesystem and see how it behaves.

Comment: @Sedenion   Following your suggestion, I tried boost::filesystem. Low and behold, it worked!. No (uncaught) exceptions. In fact, it did copy the culprit file, without any issues visible,  whereas the std::filesystem approach still fails!
This makes a work-around using OS-apis unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

All thanks for the comments made. Let me summarise my findings

1. The root cause of the problem seems to be a luring hardware issue.
2. The standard c++ techniques, using std::filesystem with both overloads of fs::copy (std::system_error or exception throwing) all fail, as these functions throw an std::__ios_failure exception that cannot be caught.
   (both g++ and clang++).
3. The latter remark seems to me a bug in the implementation of 'std::filesystem::copy' in the standard `<filesystem>` as used by the mentioned compilers.
4. Boost::filesystem::copy is robust against the particular failure I experienced. If I favour robustness over using the standard, this is the way to go.